# How to expose port to external host in docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, npm

I am trying to expose a port in docker container, and try to connect application from external host but i am unable to connect.

curl request:

```
curl http://localhost:4400
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

run command:

```
docker run -p 4400:3002  dev/my-node-app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg; \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -; \
    apt-get install -y nodejs; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3002

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "server:dev"]
```

**Also tried below Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12.19.0

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3002
CMD ["npm", "run", "server:dev"]
```

But now getting error:

```
Module build failed: Error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node)
```

I think i am running it correctly but somehow there is an error in my Dockerfile, if anyone help me I'd really be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Have you already checked the container logs to see if the node service is running?

Comment: And I recommend you replace the ubuntu image for node image, it is not a good practice to use such a bit image like ubuntu.
You can replace the steps `FROM ubuntu:20.04` and   `RUN apt-get update; ...` With `FROM node:12.19.0`

Comment: @everacosta hi, i did that but that way i am getting error:

Module build failed: Error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node)

Comment: Perfect, the problem it's in the step RUN, could you try replacing that 2 step with `FROM node:12.19.0`

Comment: updated Dockerfile in the question, getting error so can't test :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl http://localhost:4400
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

It indicates that port does not point to an application.

The application is pointing to 127.0.0.1, which should be pointing to 0.0.0.0 inside Docker.